# Jenkins running java program with output data

Tags: jenkins

1. I have java program in jenkins, program get some data and save to txt file.  When i build in jenkins this project in txt file ( in
   directory on jenkins) is nothing changes.
2. How configure jenkins to save java output (System.output) to some txt file, or send another server ftp. (in Jenkins) without usinf filereadet etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a file and write to it in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/how-do-i-create-a-file-and-write-to-it-in-java)

Comment: What are you asking is not clear. Please make sure you provide all details and with correct grammar...

Comment: You cannot, Jenkins is not able to run your java application :D 
Only groovy pipelines, probably not in default, but if some plugin is installed.

Answer (score 0):

i added on Jenkins in maven configuration exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=main, and it works thanks